# How does HDFS distribute new block or files in CopyFromLocal

Tags: hdfs

I have uploaded to HDFS with CopyFromLocal a large file which gets separated into smaller blocks which are distributed over my datanodes. I'm interested in how exactly HDFS chooses where to place these blocks - does it choose a datanode completely randomly for each block (regardless of how many blocks that the datanode already holding or its spare capacity?) or is there some method behind the choice? Is this the same as the rules for when you upload many (small) files?

I'm aware there are rules for placement of replicas, but at the moment I'm not looking at the details of replicated file placement but the placement of the original file itself.

cheers
Ellie

Answer (score 0):

Rack Awareness is a concept were NameNode is aware of which Data Node resides within which Rack , and which datanode should pick.